# Jqmobile Pages - elments from second page are seen on first page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Like the title says, I have an html 5 app that uses jqmobile and pages to make page transitions.

The transitions work fine...the only problem is that all of the elements from the second page can be seen on the first page! After I switch pages, the transition works perfectly and only elements from the second div can be seen.

Does anyone know what's going on? Maybe I'm missing a display:none somewhere?

EDIT Here's some of my code.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-one" data-title="Page 1" style = "padding-top:50px;">

            <div class = "pagecontent">
                <div id="nav">
                    navbar
                </div>

                <div id="innerdiv">
                    <div id="scroller" style="width:100%;height:100%;">

                        <div id="pullDown">
                            <span class="pullDownIcon"></span><span class="pullDownLabel">Pull down to refresh...</span>
                        </div>

                        <div id="container49">
                            <div class="circlecontainer" id="circle" >
                                <div class = "gymname">
                                    Rec. Hall
                                </div>
                                <div class="animatedcircle">
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stationarycircle">
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner" id = "innerfour">
                                    <div class="count" id="count"><span id="counter"></span><span id="percent"></span></div>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <div class="fraction" id="fraction"><span id="attend"></span><span id="max"></span></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "oc" id ="oc1">
                                    CLOSED
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="circlecontainer" id="circle2" onclick="predictor(1)">
                                <div class = "gymname">
                                    White Building
                                </div>
                                <div class="animatedcircle">
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stationarycircle">
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas4" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                                </div>

                                <div class="inner" id = "innerthree">
                                    <div class="count" id="count2"><span id="counter2"></span><span id="percent2"></span></div>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <div class="fraction" id="fraction2"><span id="attend2"></span><span id="max2"></span></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "oc" id="oc2">
                                    CLOSED
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="circlecontainer" id="circle3" onclick="predictor(2)">
                                <div class = "gymname">
                                    IM Building
                                </div>
                                <div class="animatedcircle">
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas5" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stationarycircle">
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas6" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                                </div>

                                <div class="inner" id = "innertwo">
                                    <div class="count" id="count3"><span id="counter3"></span><span id="percent3"></span></div>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <div class="fraction" id="fraction3"><span id="attend3"></span><span id="max3"></span></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "oc" id="oc3">
                                    CLOSED
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="circlecontainer" id="circle4" onclick="predictor(3)">
                                <div class = "gymname">
                                    Fitness Loft
                                </div>
                                <div class="animatedcircle">
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas7" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stationarycircle">
                                    <canvas id="myCanvas8" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                                </div>

                                <div class="inner" id = "innerone">
                                    <div class="count" id="count4"><span id="counter4"></span><span id="percent4"></span></div>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <div class="fraction" id="fraction4"><span id="attend4"></span><span id="max4"></span></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "oc" id = "oc4">
                                    CLOSED
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- content 49 -->
                    </div><!-- page content -->

                </div><!-- poopie -->
            </div><!-- scroller -->

        <a href="#page-two" id="two" data-transition="slide"></a>
        </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page-two" data-title="Page 2">
<div class = "pagecontent">

<div id="date">0/0/00</div>
<div id = "pattend">Predicted Attendance:</div>
<div id="percent"><span id="percentage">0</span>%</div>
<div id="displayattend">0</div>

<div id="wrapping">
    <div id="linediv">
        <div id="time"><span id="hours"></span>:<span id="min"></span><span id="ampm">   </span></div>
        <div id="line"></div>
         </div>

       <div id="chart1" style="height:100%;width:100%;"></div>
     </div><!--  wrapping  -->
   </div><!--   Page Content   -->
</div>
```

Comment: I am using a link to switch pages that I click pragmatically via javascript

Comment: It looks like all of the elements that are from the second page are being rendered over top of the elements form the first page.                                                                                                                                     I could really use some help with this if anyone has any bright ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The two places that you have `<div class="pagecontent">` should be `<div data-role="content">`

Comment: Please update the code you have above with the changes you just made and I will take another look. Also, what version of jquery mobile are you using?

Comment: I was ablt to put a bit of a band-aid on it by making the z-index of the first page '1' and the z-index of other pages '0' or less. I know this probably isn't the best way to accomplish what I want but it's the best I could come up with. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And you are sure you changed class="pagecontent" to data-role="content" and not just change "pageconent" to "content"? That is weird. I have never seen that before. Setting the z-index is a bad fix, but it is a fix.